# When to use "among" instead of "between"

Tags: word-choice

In the following sentence, shouldn't "among" be used instead of "between?"  It has been determined between all three departments that the science department is the most appropriate department to be in charge of this assignment.

Comment: Between you, me, and the fencepost, it's not all that important.

Comment: The 'between two, among three or more' rule-of-thumb is woefully inadequate. 'Hyde lies between Ashton, Mottram, and Stockport.' / 'There was an agreement between Groucho, Chico and Harpo ... .'